When filling out job applications do you put the company's legal address or the address you worked at?
I am a bit confused since I haven't been in this situation before but I work for a company that is legally located at city A. This is reflected on my W-2s. However, I physically work in city B.
I noticed that job applications ask the city, zip code, and state of the company you worked for. Which is a normal question but in my case - am I supposed to put that company's legal address as "City A" or the address of the physical location I worked in which would be "City B"?
This is all very confusing and I just want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Are you working remotely from another location or working at a secondary company location?

Physically in the office at a secondary location, but it's not tied to the HQ building that appears as the company's address when you search it and it's also not their legal address.

Use either address. It doesn't matter. Nobody is going to call you out for using either one.

It depends, on your resume, you put your city. But if it's for verifying references, then you put the address of the HQ/HR department. But even if you make a mistake, it's no big deal.

For corporate jobs I would put work location, but I would just give that as the city worked in unless the application explicitly asks for more or you were actually working for a franchise or other company that was just selling the bigger company's products. (Working at a burger chain is usually not working for the chain, but for a small business owner who has franchised that chain's branding and supplies.)
